# Xamarin error: Unable to open text symbol file obj\Debug\R.txt: Permission denied "R.txt: Permission denied"

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

In VS 2017 I have created new cross-platform project (Mobile App with `Xamarin.Forms`). Just after IDE finished creating all files, I tried to build solution and got this error:

> Unable to open text symbol file obj\Debug\R.txt: Permission denied
>   "R.txt: Permission denied".

IDE has standard configuration, nothing was changed. Installed SDK are Android 7.1 (API level 25) and Android 8.1 (API level 27). My AVD is configured to Android 7.1, x86 processor and Nexus 6 base device, but I think it doesn't matter in this case, because I only want to build predefinied "Hello world" app. Target framework is set to Android 8.1.

Any idea why i'm still getting this error and how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After few more minutes of research I ran VS 2017 with admin privileges and tried to build my app again. After that I've noticed BitDefender IS notofication about potential ransomware attack. It was false-positive ofcourse, but `aapt.exe` application has been blocked. Adding it to whitelist resolved all problems.